# {"message":"Method Not Allowed"} on echo framework

Tags: go, methods

When I enter the URI `http://localhost:9000/dashboard` or any other URI that uses the http POST method I always get errors, this is my handler
`e.POST("/dashboard", controller.Dashboard)`

Comment: Please provide the actual error as well. A sample curl command and its output should be good for such questions.

Comment: It's hard to debug code we can't see.

Comment: thanks, it was solved

Answer (score 0):

When you type an URL into a browser, it will send a GET. To handle it you must use `e.GET("/dashboard", controller.Dashboard)` in your application.

If the page contains a form that submits a POST, you must handle both GET and POST. Both can be mapped to `controller.Dashboard` if desired, but it is normally easier to use different handlers.